# ¿cuál es la diferencia entre los atributos href y src?

Tags: javascript

¿En que momento usar uno y otro? ¿Pueden usarse de manera intercambiable?

```
<a href="URL">Enlace</a> o <a src="URL">Enlace</a>
```

Comment: El elemento `<a>` no cuenta con un atributo `src`. Por lo que en este caso, siempre debes usar `href`

Comment: Siguiendo la idea de @Yussef, puedes ver que [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) no muestra ningun atributo llamado `src`.

Answer (score 2):

[**src**](https://www.w3.org/TR/image-resource/) : su significado es SOURCE, el tipo de uso es para agregar una **imagen** un archivo un b64 entre otros

[href](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/anchors.html): significa hypertext link, se usa para enlazar paginas , en otras palabras hipervincular paginas entre si

En conclusion

> src : inserta un objeto
>
> href: es una un link de referencia a otra pagina web

P.D en cada enlace hago referencia a la W3C que es el standard HTML

Comment: No se puede usar los dos atributos en una sola etiqueta. El atributo `href` se usa en las etiquetas **link**, **a**, **iFrame**; y el atributo `src` en las etiquetas: **video**, **source**, **img**, **audio**; por ejemplo. Pero si se puede usar de forma anidado: `<a href=" "> <img src=" "></a>`

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz toda la razon, me base a la W3C y no vi si se podia hacer, he cambiado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

href para navegar, para ir cambiando entre páginas o secciones de páginas.

src se usa para que el navegador muestre contenido integrado, cuando quieres mostrar una imagen, video, audio, etc.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).